# Form Input Array to MySQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, forms

I have a html form that allows users to add equipment to a database. One user can add multiple items of equipment, sometimes the only field that differs between the equipment is the *inventory number* and *MAC address*.

For example, they might want to add 10 x Dell PCs, with identical hardware. Rather than have them submit 10 forms, they can dynamically add **Inventory Number** and **MAC Address** fields.

The form inputs look like this;

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="make">
    <input type="text" name="model">
    <input type="text" name="inv[]">
    <input type="text" name="mac[]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I am able to submit the form, and the output of `print_r($_POST)` is;

```
Array
(
    [make] => Dell
    [model] => Optiplex
    [inv] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1544778
            [1] => 3344558
            [2] => 1644758
            [3] => 9844558
        )
    [mac] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8877445
            [1] => 3311554
            [2] => 7788445
            [3] => 3214857
        )
)
```

In the example above, I need to create *four* separate records in the mysql database.

Thinking that I needed to loop over these values and insert them individually, I have the following PHP;

```
$arr_inv = $_POST['inv'];
$arr_mac = $_POST['mac'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_inv); $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (make, model, inv, mac)
    VALUES ('" . $make . "', '" . $model . "', '" . $arr_inv[$i] . "','" . $arr_mac[$i];
    $stmt = DB::exec($sql);
}
```

While this does work, and inserts 4 individual records to the db, is it the best approach / how can I make it more efficient?

Please ignore any security flaws with the code, still working on it. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You can used `json_encode` to add it in db. And for display you can used `json_decode`.

Comment: You should always work with secured queries, this can't be ignored as you could just forget to prepare before sending to production server. Apart from this, your code is okay but should be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I think

Comment: If you need to add specific data as specific  column in DB , then you can use [PDO exec() and commit ][1] . 

If you don't need specific column for specific data you can try the was  hardik solanki  has explained.


  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can combine all rows to one `INSERT` query - exact syntax may depends on what DB you use but in general it should follow like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (make, model, inv, mac)
VALUES
(make1, model1, inv1, mac1),
(make2, model2, inv2, mac2)
```

If you have to execute a lot of queries - that could significantly improve performance.

**UPD.** As @Vatev fairly suggested I remove code examples as it doesn't contains any data escaping and validating so it could cause potential breach in someone project, so I just leave common idea description.

Comment: Please don't post answers containing SQL injections. People routinely copy these into production code.